# How to create query expression for Odata for get by Id

Tags: c#, odata, wcf-rest, wcf-web-api

I have created an OData service and now I am trying to consume this service at client side. I wants to create an expression such as for the below url in the c# query expression-

[http://odata.org/Product-Service/Product(150)](http://odata.org/Product-Service/Product%28150%29)

The above url is working fine in browsers but I want to create query expression in the C# for the above url. Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `DataServiceContext` + `DataServiceQuery` in `System.Data.Services.Client` to hit the Url. Remember no query is executed until the call to First() due to lazy loading.

```
var context = new DataServiceContext(new Uri("http://odata.org/Product-Service"), DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3);
var query = context.CreateQuery<Product>("Product");
Product product = query.Where(p => p.Id == 150).First();
```

The above should resolve to [http://odata.org/Product-Service/Product(150)](http://odata.org/Product-Service/Product%28150%29) which you can check by looking at the `query.Entities` collection. Each entity in the collection will contain a Uri.

Also if your Product class contains a navigation property, you will need to add the expand query option thus:

```
var query = context.CreateQuery<Product>("Product").
   AddQueryOption("$expand", "NavigationProperty");
```