# Return a single entity from OData - .Net

Tags: c#, .net, linq, odata

I need to do a request on an OData service that would retrieve a single entity and that should look like this:
[/EntitySet(par1=value1,…,parn=valuen)](http://server.com/odata_srv/EntitySet(par1=value1,%E2%80%A6,parn=valuen))

However, my LINQ generated query for fetching the entry looks like this:
[/EntitySet()?$filter=(par1 eq value1) and (par2 eq value2) and ... (parn eq valuen)](http://server.com/odata_srv/EntitySet()?$filter=(par1%20eq%20value1)%20and%20(par2%20eq%20value2)%20and%20...%20(parn%20eq%20valuen))

This is, of course, valid. But the server does not allow it. It only agrees with the first option, the one with the criteria in parentheses.

Is there something I can do? It would be a shame to manually create the query URL...

Here's the code:

```
        var context = new CHART_SRV_Entities(oDataUri);

        var query = context.ApplicationData.Where(ad =>
            ad.institution == "1" &&
            ad.patientId == "2000118" &&
            ad.caseId == "2488");

        DataServiceCollection<ApplicationData> data = new DataServiceCollection<ApplicationData>(context);

        data.LoadCompleted += (s, args) =>
            {
                if (args.Error == null)
                {
                    if (data.Continuation != null)
                    {
                        data.LoadNextPartialSetAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var result = data;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(args.Error.Message);
                }
            };

        data.LoadAsync(query);
```

**Update:** A "parentheses request" was achieved with CreateQuery [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493451/how-to-create-query-expression-for-odata-for-get-by-id). However, that's a synchronous call. Any ideas on how to make it async?

**Update2:** Seems that what I'm trying to achieve is an OData composite key lookup. There's this [OData library](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/wiki/Retrieving-a-single-row-by-key) that can do it, but I find it hard to believe that this can't be done with the Microsoft toolset.

Comment: Try removing the parentheses after entity set "~/EntitySet?$filter=(par1 eq value1) and (par2 eq value2) and ... (parn eq valuen)". What is your service built with?

Comment: Removing the parentheses returned same response from server: Method 'APPLICATIONDATA_GET_ENTITYSET' not implemented in data provider class
It is an SAP Gateway service btw

Answer (score 2):

Only key properties are allowed to appear in the parentheses after the entity set name.
If you are using non-key property to find the entry, you have to use the filter. This is how client works, and it is correct behavior.

In your case, I would suggest either customize client code or update the service code to support the filter, if you can.

Comment: The entity was created automatically when I added the service reference. The generated code looks like this:
[global::System.Data.Services.Common.EntitySetAttribute("ApplicationData")]  
    [global::System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceKeyAttribute("institution", "refresh", "wdConfigId", "defaultLayoutId", "patientId", "caseId", "dateFrom", "dateTo", "layoutId", "guid", "documentOu", "movementId")]
    public partial class ApplicationData : global::System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
  
I'm not sure what I can change...

Comment: There are multiple keys, but you are only specifying three of them through where clause. That means you are not to finding a single entity, but a collection of entity. So the client code HAVE TO use the filter to do what you told it to do. If you want to return a single entity, you have to specify all the key properties in the where.